# Laravel data loading using many to many relationhips

Tags: laravel, many-to-many, lazy-loading

Trying to get data using many-to-many relationships in laravel. My files and codes are described as below.

Models:

> Grade.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Grade extends Model{
    protected $guarded = [];
    public function specifications(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Specification::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function gnames(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Gname::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function gsizes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Gsize::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

> Specification.php

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
class Specification extends Model{
    protected $guarded = [];

    public function grades(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Grade::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function gnames(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Gname::Class)->withTimestamps();
    }
    public function gsizes(){
        return $this->belongsToMany(Gsize::class)->withTimestamps();
    }
}
```

My index method in SpecificaitonController is like this,

```
public function index(Specification $specification){        
  $specifications = Specification::with('grades:id,grade')->first();
  // dd($specifications);
  return view('/home.specification.index', compact('specifications'));
}
```

When I dd($specificaitons); output will be,

[image]

My purpose is to display "id(specification), specification_no, id(grades) & grade" from the specifications & grades table through the many to many relationships in the "Specification & Grade" models. The View is like below.

```
@forelse ($specifications as $specification)
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="text-left">{{ $specification->id }}</a></td>
      <td class="text-left">{{ $specification->specification_no }}</td>
      <td class="text-left">{{ $specification->grades->grade }}</td>
      <td><a href="/specifications/{{ $specification->id }}/edit">Edit</a></td>
    </tr>                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
  </tbody>
@empty
  <p><strong>No data to preview</strong></p>
@endforelse
```

At last I ended up with error below.

> ErrorException Trying to get property 'id' of non-object

I've tried many ways to get loose from this confusion.  I want to know that I am on the right approach, any helps will be appreciated to identify this error.

Comment: did you try dd($specification) inside the forelse?

Comment: @Psycho :  Yes I did. within the forelse it returns true. but outside the forelse dd($specifications) returns similer data as same as in above image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the problem according to your reply of my comment. In your controller, you are using `->first()` rather you should use `->get()` to get a collection of specifications and then `foreach/forelse` that collection in the blade.

```php
public function index(Specification $specification){        
  $specifications = Specification::with('grades:id,grade')->get();
  return view('/home.specification.index', compact('specifications'));
}
```

Comment: Appreciate your reply & it solved one issue. But when I try to access the grades table data through the specification, it can not display the grade name, id. I can display '<td class="text-left">{{ $specification->grades }}</td>'. It will display whole grades data and pivot table data, but not display the **grade**. How can I access it?

Comment: your relationships are many-to-many so it is normal/okay to get a list of grades with that realation according to the docs. what you have to do is either `change relation of specification and grade from many-to-many to many-to-one` or `inside the forelse: again forelse $grades to get each $grade to access its fields/columns i.e. id,grade etc`

Comment: According to your suggestion, I update the view as follow '@foreach ($specification->grades as $grade)
        <td class="text-left">{{ $grade->grade }}</td>
@endforeach'

Comment: did it work like you are expecting?

Comment: Yes Sure, it works fine & appreciate. Anyway if I change the $specificaitons in controller to  **$specifications = Specification::with(['grades:id,grade','gnames:id,gname','gsizes:id,gsize'])->get();**, what will be the best way to display the properties of gnames & gsizes? I am trying to concat the grade, grade name, grade size into table cell as follows **grade-gname-gsize**.

Comment: If it works fine then you can accept my answer. About gname-gsize, you could take them in the same table grade as you need them to be together, then why have you taken them in different tables in the first place? basic table structures should be strong and their architecture is very important

Comment: It is due to three different tables have multiple data like specifications have many-to-many with grades, grades have many-to-many with gnames and gsizes and specifications have many-to-many with gnames & gsizes. That's why it's coming from different tables.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239629/discussion-between-md40-and-psycho).

Answer (score 0):

in Specification Model  public function grades(){ return $this->belongsToMany(Grade::class,'grades','id')->withTimestamps();}

Comment: My relationships are according to the laravel naming convention. Therefore I think it is not required to add those fields into a relationship. See my dd() output. it returns all the data that I am trying to display. The problem may be the way of calling the functions through the relationships. Anyway I tried your suggesstion and end up with an error.